# Une publicité « prodiversité » : le préfixe est-il pro- ou s'agit-il d'une réduction/influence de « (faisant la) promotion (de) » etc. ?

Tags: sens, préfixes, antonyme

Suite à la [demande](https://www.lapresse.ca/international/amerique-latine/201904/26/01-5223687-une-publicite-prodiversite-retiree-a-la-demande-du-president-bresilien.php) d'un dirigeant raciste, une publicité « prodiversité » a été retirée au Brésil. En français l'élément [*pro-*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/pro-) est « employé principalement avec le sens « en faveur de, partisan »» ([BDL](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=3144)). La diversité raciale et sexuelle est un fait. L'élément *pro-* peut-il signifier « mettre en valeur » et cela relève-t-il d'une confusion avec le mot *promotion*, prodiversité est-il formé avec une réduction de *promotion* qui serait préfixée ; peut-on être construire un terme avec l'élément *pro-*, voire avec l'antonyme [*anti-*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/anti-) pour *en faveur/contre* un fait ; *prodiversité* est-il un antonyme de *raciste* ; dans « publicité prodiversité » le deuxième terme est-il un adjectif, quelle est sa fonction ?

Answer (score 2):

La *diversité* concerne tous les domaines de la société : culture, géolocalisation, groupe social,âge, activité, choix de vêtement … à l’infini puisse que par essence deux personnes ne se ressemblent pas.

L’antonyme ne peut être limité à une seule composante de la diversité, le racisme, mais doit prendre en compte tout le domaine de cette dernière.

Si l’on utilise les *synonymes* :

> **pro**-*diversité* opposé à **anti**-*hétérogénéité*

Si on utilise les *contraires*  :

> **pro**-*diversité* opposé à **pro**-*ressemblance*, **pro**-*monotonie*

Le titre a politisé le mot *diversité* en surajoutant l’*intention* (pro-), imposée par un pouvoir, en réponse à une publicité qui ne mettait en valeur que la seule diversité de la jeunesse.

Il y a donc une manipulation du mot pour imposer un point de vue ou pour mettre en valeur un argument ; que ce mot soit adjectif ou nom (pro/anti-philosophie, pro/anti-homosexuels pour rester dans l’univers de l’article) ne change rien à l’affaire.

Comment: Tes réflexions sur l'antonymie et les contraires sont intéressantes. Si je comprends bien la qualification de « prodiversité » ici résulte du recadrage dans l'arène du politique. Il en découlerait que la qualification est inadéquate pour décrire la pub mais adéquate pour décrire la réaction à la pub ?

Comment: @Survenant9r7 — C’est le sens de ma réponse. Les bases de la manipulation du langage tiennent à ce que la réponse, voire la présentation, limite le contexte dont on parle, pour ne voir que ce qui intéresse le locuteur et de rejeter/nier/empêcher tout autre point de vue. L’interrogation de ta question limitait l’antonyme au racisme et renvoyait à la négritude brésilienne sans inclure tout les autres motifs de rejets liés à la diversité intrinsèque de l’humanité, alors que l’analyse dans ton commentaire correspond à la situation contextualisée.

Comment: @Survenant9r7   … la pub décide de toucher un public, une cible, elle n’est pas pro-diversité. Son choix est remis en question par le politique qui a fait de la diversité réelle un danger pour ses intérêts … le journaliste constate la réponse et révèle l’intention politique en pointant la motivation de la censure.

Answer (score 1):

Je pense qu'ici, sans rentrer dans les détails techniques, *prodiversité* veut tout simplement dire « en faveur de la diversité ».

Comment: Stp entre dans les détails techniques. Comment une publicité peut « être en faveur » d'un état de fait. Au Brésil il y a des noirs, des jeunes, des gens aux orientations sexuelles diverses ; une publicité qui montre une réalité peut-elle être adéquatement qualifiée de « en faveur de » ?